# need to store values from fetched array into new array

Tags: php, mysql

**i have a code like this**

```
  $table=table_name;
  $sql="SELECT * from $table where student_id='X' and
        class='Y' and section='Z'";
  $result=$conn->query($sql);
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
  { 
    $column[]=$row; 
  }
//printing $columns array
print_r($column);
```

**output**

```
ARRAY ( [0] => ARRAY ( [0] => 1 [SNO] => 1 [1] => 21DBAAACAC0 [STUDENT_ID] => 21DBAAACAC0 [2]
 => WEEKEND [EXAM_NAME] => WEEKEND [3] => 8TH-STANDARD [CLASS] => 8TH-STANDARD [4] =>
 A [SECTION] => A [5] => 0 [PERCENTAGE] => 0 [6] => 2021-03-29 [CONDUCTED_DATE]
 => 2021-03-29 [7] => [TELUGU] => [8] => 35 [ENGLISH] => 35 [9] => [MATHEMATICS] => [10] =>
 [SOCIAL] => [11] => [HINDI] => [12] => [SCIENCE] => [13] => [NATURAL SCIENCE] => ) )
```

**i need to store column names in to an array like this**

```
column[0]=sno;
column[1]=student_id;
column[2]=exan_name;
column[3]=class; and so on..
```

**ultimately i need column names(of dynamically created table) into an array**

Answer (score 0):

well you can use:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //code here
}
```

you'll have an associative array like this:

```
$row(
    "column_key0" => "column_value0",
    "column_key1" => "column_value"
    //and so on
);
```

then you can access it with a foreach

```
foreach ($row as $column_key => $value) {
    //code here ($column_key is the name of your column)
};
```

then you can do what you want like save it in another array checking for duplicates or simply use it for your needs.
This way also if you don't know the table structure you can use column names.
so:

```
$result_set = $result->fetch_assoc();
foreach ($result_set as $row) { // here you can replace with as $row_number => $row if needed
    foreach ($row as $column_key => $column_value){
        //code here ($column_key is the name of your column)
    }
};
```

is the final result;

Comment: forech not working it returning array again for each value of a key......it showing->Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms template\architectui-html-pro\gaurdian.php on line 282
0=>Array 1=>array .....

Answer (score 0):

**use following code to get keys of associative array**

```
<?php 
   
   $new = call_user_func_array('array_merge', 'array name here');
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($new)-1;$i++)
    {
      echo $new[$i]."<br>"; 
    }
?>
```

**it will give output**

```
sno(column 1 name)
student_name(column 2 name)
student_id(column 3 name)...up to size-1
```